# How to configure parallelSolverCount in Optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm running a batch of solutions and I'm trying to configure the parallelSolverCount using:

```
  <solver>
      <solverManagerConfig>
          <parallelSolverCount>1</parallelSolverCount>

        </solverManagerConfig>
....
</solver>
```

But it's not waiting and I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The problemId (1) is already solving.
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.lambda$solve$1(DefaultSolverManager.java:116)
```

What's the right syntax to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SolverManager` cannot be configured via XML.

If you create a `SolverManager` instance yourself, you can pass a `SolverManagerConfig` object as the second argument to the factory method:

```java
SolverConfig solverConfig
        = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(".../cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml");
SolverManager solverManager
        = SolverManager.create(solverConfig, new SolverManagerConfig().withParallelSolverCount("1"));
```

If you use Quarkus or Spring Boot and have the `SolverManager` instance injected by the framework, then try setting the parallel solver count using the `optaplanner.solver-manager.parallel-solver-count` property either as a system property (`-Doptaplanner.solver-manager.parallel-solver-count=1`) or in `application.properties`:

```ini
optaplanner.solver-manager.parallel-solver-count=1
```

You can find more about `SolverManager` configuration in the [documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#solverManager).